# Powershell 3.0: Returning a list of file names with last write times within the past 24 hours

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that checks, recursively, all folders and file names in a directory, and then returns the names and last write times to a text file. I only want the names of files and folders that have been added within the past twenty four hours.

```
$date = Get-Date

Get-ChildItem 'R:\Destination\Path' -recurse |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date -gt $date.AddDays(-1) } |
Select LastWriteTime, Name > 'C:\Destination\Path\LastWriteTime.txt' |
Clear-Host
Invoke-Item 'C:\Destination\Path\LastWriteTime.txt'
```

The .txt file that is invoked is blank, which, based on the test conditions I have set up should not be the case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a logical **and**. Change:

```
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date -gt $date.AddDays(-1) }
```

to

```
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date.AddDays(-1) }
```

Even better to use parenthesis, if you would have used them then the syntax would not have been parsed with the missing **AND**:

```
Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $date) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $date.AddDays(-1)) }
```

Comment: Derp! I tried "and" earlier but it didn't work. That's because I failed to write "-and". Once I took the "and" out, the code parsed, so I thought the error existed elsewhere. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome - note the edit I made about using parenthesis.

Comment: Excellent! If it's not inappropriate to ask in the comment section, do you know if it's possible to organize the information that this script returns? More specifically, it appears that it returns information in a hierarchy, so that the list looks like: folder A, folder B, folder C, contents of A, contents of B, contents of C. Is it possible to list the folder and the contents sequentially?

Comment: I figured it out! Well, sort of. Sort-Object does a good job of organizing the files but it's still a bit messy. For now, it'll work!